# How to use refresh method in ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to update visibility option in the columDefs of my ui-grid. After updating the value I need to refresh my ui-grid. What is the way to refresh my grid from my controller?

Answer (score 41):

Visit this pages:

- GetAPI - http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridApi
- Specific API - http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridApi

After having instantiated your gridApi, you can just call:

```
//instantiate (not so obvious)
// whatever scope attribute your binding to gridOptions
$scope.gridOptions = {
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ $scope.gridApi = gridApi;}
}
//then later
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had a ui-grid with a total row and when some amount in a cell was updated from my code, the totals for that cell didn't update. This solution solved the issue.

Comment: Answer needs expanding to explain how to instantiate gridApi.

Comment: But such expanding would require quite another question.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your need you can change the following ui-grid option

`enableRowHashing:false`

Comment: I'm only updating data in place, so no array length or other super smart grid watches were triggered, thus I had to ng-if the grid out of the DOM and insert it after. with `enableRowHashing:false` it's working now without ng-if. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN); method after you modify the column defs and then refesh the grid .

More Details on
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.service:uiGridConstants#properties_datachange