# how to refresh ui-grid before apply data sorting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to sorting an ui-grid table rows ascending and descending in base to one column selection. My problem is When I call to the api it only give me the last 100 results, so If I try to show the 100 littlest results I need to send new request to the api and refresh table data.

What is the best way to refresh the table data when user click on the sorting button and  Before apply the sorting function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use refresh method in ui-grid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634063/how-to-use-refresh-method-in-ui-grid)

Comment: Is not the solution I need. i need to send a http request before sorting